# add item to application from controller in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

from my controller I want to assign a value to an application variable much like I would a session variable.

I assumed I could just use:

```
Application("MyValue") = "test"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HttpContext.Application["MyValue"] = test
```

Comment: lol, I was trying to do httpcontext.current.application - doh! - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use this to pass data from the controller to the view, use the ViewData.

```
ViewData("MyValue") = "test"
```

If not, please give more context as to what you are trying to accomplish.